# Is it possible to use Ubuntu One on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu

Is it possible to install and use Ubuntu One on Ubuntu Server for backup purpose? Instructions on `one.ubuntu.com` only shows how to use it on Ubuntu desktop with Gnome :(.

Maybe where are some developers blogs / forum posts that reveals current plans for coexistence of ubuntu one service and ubuntu server os?

Comment: as an aside, dropbox also works on command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, hopefully this will help: [Command Line](http://joysofprogramming.com/u1sdtool-ubuntu-one-command-line-tutorial/).

Clicking "How to start the Ubuntu One Sync Daemon?" starts you off.

Further info here: [Man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/u1sdtool.1.html).